# mysql syntax error

Tags: mysql, syntax

I have the following query :

```
select irc.*,p.*,@product :='prod_product',@accessrole :='pub_accessrole' 
from item_rel_coupon irc 
join user_rel_coupon urc on urc.userId = 7 and irc.couponId=urc.couponId 
left join if(irc.source='product',@product,@accessrole) as p on p.id=irc.itemId
```

But I get a syntax error. Why?

Comment: What's the exact error MySQL is giving you? Should help pinpoint which bit is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nanne is right, your IF() is not a table. There are two ways around:

1. You join on both tables, and put the
   IF in your select to select the
   columns from the table you want.
   (recommended)
2. You use the IF to create the query
   in a string, you PREPARE the string
   and EXECUTE the handle. (not
   recommended)

Answer (score 0):

This part gives an error:<sup>1</sup>

```
left join if(irc.source='product',@product,@accessrole) as p on p.id=irc.itemId
```

I after a JOIN you need a table reference, and I don't think your `if` 's result is one.

<sup>1</sup>: the error:
*#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if(irc.source='product',@product,@accessrole) as p on p.id=irc.itemId LIMIT 0,' at line 1*

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I've ever seen an IF() used as a table reference in a query, especially if the IRC source can alternate between different sources... I would change to...

```
select 
      irc.*,
      if( p1.id = irc.itemid, p1.fld1, p2.fld1 ) as Fld1,
      if( p1.id = irc.itemid, p1.fld2, p2.fld2 ) as Fld2,
      if( p1.id = irc.itemid, p1.fld3, p2.fld3 ) as Fld3,
      if( p1.id = irc.itemid, p1.fld4, p2.fld4 ) as Fld4
   from 
      item_rel_coupon irc 
         join user_rel_coupon urc 
            on urc.userId = 7 
            and irc.couponId=urc.couponId 
         left join prod_product p1
            on p1.id = irc.itemid
         left join pub_accessrole p2
            on p2.id = irc.itemid
```